# Is Source={x:Reference this} required always when I have a Xamarin Template binding?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's an example of a template that I use (shortened for the benefit of this question).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
x:Class="Japanese.SwitchTemplate" x:Name="this">
    <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding GridVisible, Source={x:Reference this}}">
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Can someone explain to me why I need to have:

```
Source={x:Reference this}
```

and is there a way to avoid having this for every binding variable in the templates I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you posted, you don’t need to specify the source for binding.

Source is needed when you define a data template. For example, ListView. You provide a data source, but there is a binding in the template that is bound to a different object in the binding context of the page itself or another control.

Without understanding more about what you are trying to do, I cannot say if they can be avoided.